Doing a VARMA model but ran into some issues with ECCM and non invertible matrices
Im using the MTS package since I'm basing myself on Tsay (2014). I'm trying to fit a model with mexican unemployment rates and CPI. doing the eccm I get:




0
1
2
3
4
5
6




0
0.0000
0.0052
0.0560
0.0616
0.0276
0.0129
0.1035


1
0.0000
0.0000
0.5188
0.0659
0.0003
0.0022
0.6971


2
0.0003
0.0261
0.0001
0.0005
0.0000
0.0101
0.2774


3
0.0015
0.0408
0.0448
0.0010
0.0022
0.0161
0.1256


4
0.0037
0.0160
0.1507
0.7338
0.0768
0.4615
0.3397


5
0.0650
0.2512
0.3963
0.8729
0.8839
0.6567
0.9994



So i thought VARMA(1,2), VARMA(2,1) where good options. The problem is that R tells me that when they try to solve matrices they get NaNs. But if I do a VARMA(2,0) I get no problems.
Am I choosing right? and if so, what should i do?

Please use capital letter where appropriate, such as for I (not i) and at the beginning of a sentence. Thank you.
